# Protractor gives wrong selector error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

so I've just been trying to integrate my angular project with protractor and I've run into problem. I have a markup of html like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, myLstItem) in shadowMyLst" class="show-on-hover-subject" ng-click="editSurvey(myLstItem.id, myLstItem.name, 1)" id="questionnaire-{{key}}">
     ...
</tr>
```

and my protractor markup is like this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    browser.driver.get(CI_URL);

    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('ci-email-login')).sendKeys(CI_EMAIL);
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('ci-username-login')).sendKeys(CI_USERNAME); 
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('ci-go-login')).click();

    browser.driver.sleep(1);
    browser.waitForAngular();


    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('questionnaire-0')).click();
});
```

when I run it, I get this error:

```
Failed: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="questionnaire-0"]"}
```

I am using `by.id` as a selector and it says that im using a css selector. Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: did you inspect the html document if id="questionnaire-0" is rendered properly?

Comment: Yes. I also added the `browser.waitForAngular();` just to make sure that the ng-repeat was finished before finding the element. It was there alright, the problem is it can't find the element because for some reason, Protractor says I'm using a css selector while in my code I'm using `by.id`.

Comment: It looks like webdriver converted your by.id locator to a css selector.  Is the login process where you enter the credentials an angular page?.. If it's not waitForAngular might not help..

Comment: Yup it's an angular page. Removed waitForAngular but same error.

Comment: Well, it will pick the first element present in the DOM. Since it is an angular try to use protractor methods directly  "element(by.id("xyz"));" 
And try to use some implicit wait, until the element is present, to do particular action. The sleep is in millions seconds you gave it as 1, that does not change anything.

Comment: Just added browser.wait with a set time, still didn't help. This is the error `Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="questionnaire-0"])`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I was repeating the object twice in the page and I only added IDs to one ng-repeat. Protractor wasn't detecting that, added IDs to both, now it works okay. Thanks for the help.